# How to run Azure Web job using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I created a web job (Console Application) on **azure** for copying one container blob to another and register on Azure.

It is working properly.

But I want to call the this from c# code not azure scheduler.

How is it possible ?

Like  :-

```
 if (Check == true)
                {
 //Run Web Job Code here
}
```

Comment: Possibly related...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265546/can-i-invoke-an-azure-webjob-from-an-azure-website-and-pass-it-parameters

Comment: what do you mean by "from c# code" ? you want to execute your code on demand from an external application ?

Comment: Yes. i want to call web job from my application. like :-  if (Check == true)
                {
 //Run Web Job Code here
}

Answer (score 0):

Add an "settings.job" file to the root of your job directory. This file must contain an Cron-Expression to start the job (basic cron syntax).

```
{
  "schedule": "0 * * * * *"
}
```

runs for example, every hour.

For a more detailed description: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs