# Using Azure WebJobs for on demand responses

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I currently have a couple of WebApi projects that use a few class libraries such as address lookup, bank validation, image storage etc.

Currently they are all in a shared solution but I'm planning to split them up. I thought about moving the libraries into NuGet packages so that they are separate from the API projects and is properly shared.

However, if I make a change to one of these components I will need to build and redeploy the API service even though it's a separate component which has changed.

I thought about putting these components into a separate service but seems a bit of overhead for what it is.

I've been looking at Azure WebJobs and think I may be able to move these components into this instead. I have two questions related to this:

1. Are WebJobs suitable for calling on demand (not using a queue)? The request will be activated from a user on a web site which calls my API service which then calls the Web Job so it needs to be quick.
2. Can a WebJob return data? I've seen examples where it does some processing and updates a database but I need a response (ideally Json) back to my API service.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you going to have the same problem though?  If your WebJob is hosted under an AppService in Azure, what's the difference between deploying a WebAPI and deploying a WebJob?

Comment: I assume I can deploy a new version of the WebJob without having to touch the API service?

Comment: According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265546/can-i-invoke-an-azure-webjob-from-an-azure-website-and-pass-it-parameters) your plan will not work.  There is currently no way to pass parameters to a WebJob when attempting to invoke it.  Further, a WebJob is implemented as a "`public static void`" method, so you won't be able to return data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, I assume that you could try to leverage Azure Functions by creating a function using the HTTP trigger, which could be triggered by accessing the Function URL with parameters and return the response as you expected. You could follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-create-first-azure-function/) for getting started with Azure Functions.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I'm looking for! I've had a look through and see that you can deploy from a Git repository. Does this literally just copy the file over or does it compile? Reason is that I want to reference another project in the same solution, and possibly NuGet packages, can it do this?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the Azure article about how to do this here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/