# How do I pass a poco to azure webjob from azure app service (azure website)?

Tags: azure, poco, sendgrid, azure-webjobs, kudu

I have an asp.net mvc 5 website running in an azure app service. My site allows customers to communicate via email uploading documents if required.

I modeled this as sending email with attachments (max 4mb) using sendgrid with azure webjob.

I cannot use an azure queue since the message size is way too small.

Therefore I have to communicate with a triggered webjob via kudu. I've read the docs and the [argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265546/can-i-invoke-an-azure-webjob-from-an-azure-website-and-pass-it-parameters) seems to be a simple [string](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job) which I can either read it off of the arguments or WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS environment variable.

My poco class to send email has customer properties (mostly string) + the file the user uploads is of type HttpPostedFileBase.

How do I pass this poco class to the triggered webjob via kudu?

Should I json serialize it and pass it as a string?

Any other options?

I need help.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use an azure queue since the message size is way too small.

That's not a limitation on Azure Queues.

> Should I json serialize it and pass it as a string?

That's basically what the azure queues is doing.

My suggestion is if you want to use Azure WebJobs to send an email, you can just send a message to a queue with the appropriate payload. When you listen to the queue you can get the attachment (maybe store it as a blob?) and send it using SendGrid.

When you listen to the message you can either get a string or POCO object. If you're going to get a POCO, I suggest not to send the HttpPostedFileBase property since that can make the message too large (that is a limitation on the message).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx for your answer If I understand correctly then the capacity and quotas section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted lists the Maximum message size  64 KB using only queues. (48 KB when using Base64 encoding). I do not want to combine queues and blobs since my client does not want to pay.

Comment: If you want the process to be sync, then just do it on your WebApp without a WebJob. WebJobs are usually used for background processes. Queues  and Blob Storage are not expensive at all.

Comment: I want the process to be async freeing up the website. I'm fairly close to what I intended. Fingers crossed on the attachment bit though.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide direction at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900044/what-errors-should-i-handle-with-polly-when-calling-google-recaptcha-in-azure since I'm not getting any help there